# Swift - defining default access level

Tags: swift

In swift 2.2, is there a way to define a default access level for multiple functions and vars, e.g., by putting something like "@public" on one line, which will then effectively make everything below it public?

Comment: Make the class itself public, then all funcs inherit the access modifier. (if this helps)

Comment: Actually, they don't, at least not in 2.2.  I cannot access functions from within a public class defined in a separate module unless they are explicitly declared as public.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, there is no such way. I think it's for the better, because it is easy to miss a specifier like this if the code isn't structured very well. The way it is now it is always easy to spot the access level right from the function/property declaration. For instance, you jump from one file to the middle of the other. If such modifiers existed, you'd have to look for a modifier to check.

Such modifiers, of course, exist in C++, for instance, but in C++ interface declarations are separated from implementations, so it is usually pretty easy to spot a modifier.

Still, Swift is Open Source now, so if you believe I'm wrong, and you have good arguments to support your position, you can make a suggestion on the [Swift Evolution](https://swift.org/community/#swift-evolution) public forum :)

Comment: I would be in favor of this.